# I decided to update all mypackages going to packages and then clicking update all. After this, I am getting several erros in lots of packages

Tags: r, r-package

The erros looks like this:

> library(ggpubr)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggpubr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.5.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required

> library(tidyverse)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.5.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required

I have uninstalled and reinstalled R and R studio, and I am still getting the same erros.
Now I can't even open my CVS files bc R does't load the packges for it. Does someone went through the same problem?

I have uninstalled and reinstalled R and R studio, and I am still getting the same erros.I expect to get my R running properly again.

Comment: You may need to update the packages i.e. `update.packages("vctrs")`

Comment: Uninstalling/reinstalling R and RStudio does not actually remove your package library paths. If you run `.libPaths()` you can see where packages are being stored. If you really want to remove everything to start clean, you can remove those files as well. Otherwise just update the packages that our out of date as indicated in the error message in this case that's the `vctrs` pacakge.

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
update.packages('vctrs')
```